# Python Google Drive API

Tags: python, api

Hello I want to upload an image to Google Drive using OAuth 3.0 Playground. it worked but every 3600 seconds the acess token is changed. Does anyone know a way to renew the token or even a completely different way. Also I need the image id in drive which I got until now using the return function.

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ###Acesstoken from Playground###"} 
para = {
    "name": "" + str(img_counter) + ".png", #file name to be uploaded
    "parents": ["###Folder id###"] 
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open("./Test.png", "rb") 
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
    
)

return(r.text)
```

Comment: It’s Oauth, why not just use the refresh flow…? It seems you’re copying/pasting the token from somewhere, why not implement the entire Oauth flow? Finally, why try to re-invent the wheel here when Google provides a library to abstract all the authentication/authorization for Drive for you?

Comment: Because i cant find a way to get the file id